# Custom update Telerik grid MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik, kendo-grid

i want to fill and **update** a kendo grid  using dynamic model because the model is not exist. i can fill the grid but when i try to excute incell update i apply the function but the result is put it in object that i can't get data from it.
i try to do a custom grid update using a dynamic model.

- The View :

I fill the grid using datatable

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
    {
        columns.Bound(column.ColumnName);
    }
    columns.Command(cmd=>cmd.Save());
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Editable(ed=>ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Filterable()
.Groupable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()        
    .Model(model =>
        {
            var id = Model.PrimaryKey[0].ColumnName;
            model.Id(id);
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
            {
             var field = model.Field(column.ColumnName,column.DataType);
                if (column.ColumnName == id)
                {
                    field.Editable(false);
                }

            }                
        })

    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home"))
)
```

)

- Controller :
  The problem is "the unknown model" when i get the list of updates as "object" that i can't access to data.

  ```
   public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest  request,  IEnumerable<dynamic>  models)
  {
         // TO-DO

      return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));


  }
  ```